# How to authenticate SpeechClient V1 using keyfile (PHP / Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to authenticate the SpeechClient using 'keyFilePath' and 'projectId' parameters like so:

```
$speech = new SpeechClient([
            'projectId' => 'actualProjectId,
            'keyFilePath' => $key_path,
        ]);
```

If I use `Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient` - Everything works fine, but if I use `Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient` I end up with an error: `Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials`

I've read [Google docs for Setting Up Authentication](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials) but still don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I need the V1 (in fact V1p1beta1) for additional features that are not available using the old SpeechClient.

Any ideas?

*P.S. Using Laravel as the back-end.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clients within the `V1`, etc. namespaces, pass the keyFilePath as `credentials`.

```
new SpeechClient([
    'credentials' => $key_path
]);
```